# Restrict Content Pro Expand Invoice Details

Tags: php, invoice

I am looking for advice on how to expand invoice details using the Restrict Content Pro Wordpress plugin. I'm unsure on how to go about showing the breakdown of a subscription level on an invoice. I've hit a learning curve with figuring this out with their code.  I've attached the invoice.php, how do I tackle this?

My connumdrum: I have a subscription that is 295$. The breakdown is: Membership fee - 195$, Insurance Policy - 100$. I just need to show the breakdown, it's probably super simple.

I did try just putting a ul tag and just list the breakdown with li tags. But, that would cause confusion because it would show up all invoices with different levels.

**Invoice Code:**

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <header id="header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo">
            <?php if ( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_logo'] ) ) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $rcp_options['invoice_logo'] );     ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Invoice Details -->
        <div class="alignright">
            <h1><?php printf( __( 'Invoice %s', 'rcp' ), $rcp_payment->id ); ?>    </h1>
        </div>

        <?php if( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_header'] ) ) : ?>
            <p><?php echo $rcp_options['invoice_header']; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header>

    <section id="contacts">
        <div class="alignleft">
            <header><?php printf( __( 'Invoice %s', 'rcp' ), $rcp_payment->id ); ?></header>

            <article>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_company'] ) ) : ?>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $rcp_options['invoice_company']; ?></strong></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_name'] ) ) : ?>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $rcp_options['invoice_name']; ?></strong></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_address'] ) ) : ?>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $rcp_options['invoice_address']; ?></strong></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_address_2'] ) ) : ?>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $rcp_options['invoice_address_2']; ?></strong></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_city_state_zip'] ) ) : ?>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $rcp_options['invoice_city_state_zip']; ?></strong></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_email'] ) ) : ?>
                    <p><strong><?php echo $rcp_options['invoice_email']; ?></strong></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </article>
        </div>

        <div class="alignright">

            <header><?php _e( 'Bill To:', 'rcp' ); ?></header>

            <article>
                <p><strong><?php echo $rcp_member->first_name . ' ' . $rcp_member->last_name; ?></strong></p>
                <p><strong><?php echo $rcp_member->user_email; ?></strong></p>
                <?php
                /**
                 * Insert content after the member's name and email.
                 *
                 * @param object     $rcp_payment Payment object from the database.
                 * @param RCP_Member $rcp_member  Member object.
                 */
                do_action( 'rcp_invoice_bill_to', $rcp_payment, $rcp_member );
                ?>
            </article>

        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Items -->
    <section id="items">

        <header><?php _e( 'Invoice Items:', 'rcp' ); ?></header>

        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="name"><?php echo $rcp_payment->subscription; ?></td>
                    <td class="price"><?php echo rcp_currency_filter( $rcp_payment->amount ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php do_action( 'rcp_invoice_items', $rcp_payment ); ?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <?php do_action( 'rcp_invoice_items_before_total_price', $rcp_payment ); ?>

                <!-- Total -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="name"><?php _e( 'Total Price:', 'rcp' ); ?></td>
                    <td class="price"><?php echo rcp_currency_filter( $rcp_payment->amount ); ?></td>
                </tr>

                <!-- Paid -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="name"><?php _e( 'Payment Status:', 'rcp' ); ?></td>
                    <td class="price"><?php echo rcp_get_payment_status_label( $rcp_payment ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </section>

    <!-- Additional Info -->
    <section id="additional-info">
        <div class="alignleft">
            <header><?php _e( 'Additional Info:', 'rcp' ); ?></header>

            <article>
                <p><?php echo __( 'Payment Date:', 'rcp' ) . ' ' . date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $rcp_payment->date, current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) ); ?></p>
            </article>

            <?php if( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_notes'] ) ) : ?>
                <article>
                    <?php echo wpautop( wp_kses_post( $rcp_options['invoice_notes'] ) ); ?>
                </article>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'rcp_invoice_additional_info', $rcp_payment ); ?>
        </div>
    </section>

    <?php do_action( 'rcp_invoice_after_additional_info', $rcp_payment ); ?>

    <footer id="footer">
        <?php if( ! empty( $rcp_options['invoice_footer'] ) ) : ?>
            <p><?php echo $rcp_options['invoice_footer']; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p class="print alignright"><a href="#" onclick="window.print()"><?php _e( 'Print', 'rcp' ); ?></a></p>
    </footer>
</div>
```